# linux centos6.6 "Errno 14 PYCURL ERROR 18 - "transfer closed with 5691386 bytes remaining to read"

Tags: linux-kernel, centos6, pycurl

when i updated centos6.6 system's kernel , Centos6.6 raised few “pycurl exceptions” .
but i could not found out problem where it exists, ，many thanks for anyone who can get me out from problem

when i executed a command " yum update kernel -y"  is all right ,but next  command （"yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel gcc make -y"）gived rise to a problem  as follows

```
yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel gcc make -y

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.btte.net
 * epel: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
 * extras: mirrors.btte.net
 * updates: mirrors.sohu.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp = 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc >= 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.2()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-504.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.1.el6 will be an update
---> Package make.x86_64 1:3.81-20.el6 will be updated
---> Package make.x86_64 1:3.81-23.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:0.8.3-0.3.svn855.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package             Arch        Version                     Repository    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel-devel        x86_64      2.6.32-696.10.1.el6         updates       11 M
Updating:
 gcc                 x86_64      4.8.2-8.el6                 hop5          17 M
 kernel-headers      x86_64      2.6.32-696.10.1.el6         updates      4.5 M
 make                x86_64      1:3.81-23.el6               base         389 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libmpc              x86_64      0.8.3-0.3.svn855.el6        hop5          47 k
Updating for dependencies:
 cpp                 x86_64      4.8.2-8.el6                 hop5         5.7 M
 libgcc              x86_64      4.8.2-8.el6                 hop5          83 k
 libgomp             x86_64      4.8.2-8.el6                 hop5         100 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       6 Package(s)

Total size: 39 M
Total download size: 23 M
Downloading Packages:
http://www.hop5.in/yum/el6/cpp-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 18 - "transfer closed with 5645719 bytes remaining to read"
Trying other mirror.
http://www.hop5.in/yum/el6/gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 18 - "transfer closed with 17650529 bytes remaining to read"
Trying other mirror.


Error Downloading Packages:
  cpp-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64: failure: cpp-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64.rpm from hop5: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64: failure: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64.rpm from hop5: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Comment: There's network issues somewhere. How many times did you try this ?

Comment: try many times ，but finally can not be through it！